# react hook conditional useState - JSON.parse(...) is null

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using react hook and I want to retrieve some information from the client's local storage if it exists.

Below is the application state I defined:

```js
const [name, setName] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personalInfo")).name || "");
```

I expect that if there is no data in the local storage then an empty string would be used as the initial state.

However, it produces an error: `TypeError: JSON.parse(...) is null`

It shows that even if local storage is empty, the empty string is still not be used as the initial state.

It works as expected before but after I added in some complex code in another components, it starts to produce errors. Any idea why this can happens so that I know where to debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
const localStore = localStorage.getItem("personalInfo")
const [name, setName] = useState(localStore ? JSON.parse(localStore).name : "");
```

or you can safely parse JSON

```
function parseJson(){
    try {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personalInfo")).name;
    } catch(ex){
      return "";
    }
}

const [name, setName] = useState(parseJson();
```